# How to animate GIFs in org-mode in emacs?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I inserted a GIF in my org file, but it was static, I want to animate it, how can I do it?

Comment: You might want to give more details, e.g. about exactly *how* you inserted that "gif", and also about what you tried to do to "animate it".  Among other things, you'll want to clarify if the "gif" is already "animated".

Comment: This might be helpful: https://ivanaf.com/animating_gifs_in_orgmode.html